# How to avoid log output DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:148 - Adding type registration ...?

Tags: hibernate, log4j

I use Hibernate and log4j for my application and I want to reduce the log output in the runtime environment to real errors.
At application start I get log entries like:

```
DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:148 - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@78f42b89
DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:148 - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@78f42b89
DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:148 - Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@78f42b89
```

How can I configure log4j and/or Hibernate to avoid these entries?

This is my current log4j config:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found a solution myself:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ERROR
```

avoids above debug messages at startup.